# Filter output of a grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

I have several grunt tasks which internally use `grunt-shell` to execute various CLI commands.

I want to hide certain logs printed to the output console by these CLI commands.

Am trying to use `grunt-reporter` for this but unable to get it working.

Gruntfile.js

```
reporter: {
            shell:{
                options: {
                    tasks: ['shell'],
                    header: false
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer...** It's not possible for `grunt-reporter` by itself to hide logs generated by a `grunt-shell` command.

**The long answer including workaround...** The logs from a `grunt-shell` command are generated by the shell/bash command itself and not via a node package/script. The [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-reporter#examples) shown on the `grunt-reporter` homepage are intercepting/manipulating a message from a node package written to `stdout`.

Consider the following...

#### Simple gist

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        shell: {
            listFiles: {
                command: 'ls src/js/*.js'
            }
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'shell:listFiles'
    ]);
};
```

Running `$ grunt` via the CLI outputs something like this:

> `Running "shell:listFiles" (shell) task`
>
> `src/js/a.js`
>
> `src/js/b.js`
>
> `src/js/c.js`
>
> `Done.`

---

#### Hide the header...

Utilizing `grunt-reporter` it's possible, *(at best for this scenario)*, to hide the header using a config as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        reporter: {
            shell: {
                options: {
                    tasks: ['shell:listFiles'],
                    header: false      
                }
            }
        },

        shell: {
            listFiles: {
                command: 'ls src/js/*.js'
            }
        }

    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'reporter:shell', //<-- Note: The reporter task is called first.
        'shell:listFiles'
    ]);

};
```

Running `$ grunt` via the CLI will now output something like this *(Note: the header has been hidden, however the log from the `ls` command persists as it directly comes from the bash/shell command)*:

> `src/js/a.js`
>
> `src/js/b.js`
>
> `src/js/c.js`
>
> `Done.`

Even after adding the [`suppress: true`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-reporter#suppress) to the `reporter` options the paths logs from the `ls` command persist.

---

#### Workaround

I think the only way to hide the logs from a CLI command will be to redirect the output messages to `/dev/null` in the 'grunt-shell' commands:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        reporter: {
            shell: {
                options: {
                    tasks: ['shell:listFiles'],
                    header: false,
                    
                }
            }
        },

        shell: {
            listFiles: {
                command: 'ls src/js/*.js > /dev/null' //<-- redirect the output messages
            }
        }

    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'reporter:shell', //<-- Note: The reporter task is called first.
        'shell:listFiles'
    ]);

};
```

This time running `$ grunt` via the CLI successfully hides the messages/logs and only reports:

> `Done.`

*Note:* The addition of `> /dev/null` will only redirect the messages/logs and any errors will continue to get reported. Using `> /dev/null 2>&1` would also hide any errors too.